# Efficiently generating a prime polynomial of a given degree

Tags: algorithms

I'm playing around with finite field arithmetic and implementing it in a little library. I'd like to be able to handle arbitrary finite fields given their size and characteristic. I don't want to write down a prime polynomial for every given possible finite field though. How can I generate a prime polynomial of a given degree for use in multiplication? To be clear I don't care which polynomial I get, and I don't want all of them. I just want any old one of a given degree. If this is an open research question what if we only try to solve it for $GF(2^n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to construct an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $GF(2)$ (as this [immediately induces an explicit construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Non-prime_fields) for $GF(2^n)$).  So, how do you generate an irreducible polynomial?

One approach is to repeatedly choose a random polynomial of degree $n$, then test whether it is irreducible.  You can test for irreducibility by factoring the polynomial over $GF(2)$.  There are [standard algorithms for polynomial factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields); they run in polynomial time.  Moreover, about a $1/n$ fraction of all polynomials are irreducible (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Analogue_for_irreducible_polynomials_over_a_finite_field)).  It follows that on average about $n$ iterations will suffice, and since each iteration can be done in polynomial time, the whole thing runs in (randomized) polynomial time.

Comment: How do we know about 1/n are irreducible? I've read that in "fast construction of irreducible polynomials over finite fields" (well actually 1/2n but same difference). The reference hits a thick textbook though.

Comment: @Jake, the linked Wikipedia page gives a sketch of how to prove that 1/n of *monic* polynomials are irreducible. But multiplying by a constant doesn't change reducibility.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, indeed -- and moreover in this case, we are working over $GF(2)$, and all polynomials over $GF(2)$ are monic.

Comment: Thinking about it, if you're working over $GF(2)$ and testing random polynomials you can easily improve the odds to $2/n$ by ensuring that you have an odd number of non-zero coefficients (i.e. don't select the constant coefficient randomly).

Answer (score 2):

In a [related question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/105543/46140), Igor Rivin provides a link to a 2009 pre-print of a paper of Couveignes and Lercier, [Fast construction of irreducible polynomials over finite fields](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1642.pdf), which uses elliptic curves to provide a probabilistic quasi-linear algorithm. The paper was published in Israel Journal of Mathematics (2013) vol. 194, pp 77–105, DOI https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-012-0070-8